# Jquey - Como tomar ações com elementos dinâmicos de uma tabela?

Tags: html, jquery, table

Estou fazendo uma tabela que é alimentada dinamicamente com valores do banco de dados. Nessa tabela criada coloquei um campo para inserir a "quantidade" e um botão desabilitado por uma classe. Eu quero habilitar o botão assim que o usuário inserir um valor no input "quantidade", mas da forma que eu tentei fazer com jquery não deu certo, só funciona nos elementos da primeira linha (produto), nos restantes não desabilita o botão.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($produtos as $produto)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $produto->codigo }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produto->produto }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produto->unidade_medida_peso }}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="inputQuantidade">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn disabled" name="addproduto" id="addproduto">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

E o que eu tentei fazer no jquery:

```
    $( "#inputQuantidade" ).keyup(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('#addproduto').removeClass("disabled");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O atributo global id define um identificador exclusivo (ID) que deve ser único por todo o documento. Como você está dentro de um `foreach` vai acontecer de existir 2 ID's e isso não pode ocorrer. No seu caso, você pode estar fazendo o uso de classes.

Segue um exemplo de como você poderia fazer a implementação:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($produtos as $produto)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $produto->codigo }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produto->produto }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produto->unidade_medida_peso }}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="inputQuantidade">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn disabled" name="addproduto" class="addproduto">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Outra coisa é que você precisa garantir que as tag's já estão no documento no momento em que você faz a execução do jQuery. Modifique seu script para seguir as instruções abaixo:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".inputQuantidade" ).keyup(function() {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.addproduto').removeClass("disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfeito! Agora funcionou. Muito obrigado, cara!